# Using the Instagram API to pull media from an user that I do not own

Tags: java, instagram-api

I want to make a web application that shows post from a user that I do not own. I want to pull images only from the users' account. I have an API key and tried many times but I get errors. https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/NAME/media/recent?max_id=XXXXXXXXXXX

Does that user need to login? The users account for which I want to pull images from is not private but how would I do this with a private account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API needs a `user-id` not `NAME`, also you need `access_token` in the url param, like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

try `3` for `{user-id}` in the above API call and you will get a response, as long as you have permission for `public_content` for you app and your app is not in sandbox mode,

(If you are in sandbox mode, then the user you are accessing should be added to your sandbox and accepted.)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with this library, that allows you to scrape public info: 
https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-java-scraper

```
List<Media> medias = instagram.getMedias("durov", 12);
System.out.println(medias.get(0).imageHighResolutionUrl);
```

Comment: FINALLY I found something helping me with my similar problem! Thanks mate!

Comment: @fusionlightcat glad it helped